# Is it possible to extract prefix from router in express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I was wondering if it is possible to extract prefix from Router in express.js.

Here is my index.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const admin = require("./admin");
const home = require("./home");

router.use("/admin", admin);
router.use("/", home);

// Catch All Other Pages
router.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.render("404", { title: "404 Not Found" });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is my admin routes file:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("admin", { title: "Admin Menu" });
});

router.get("/settings", function(req, res) {
  res.render("admin/settings", { title: "Admin Menu | Settings" });
});

router.get("/logout", function(req, res) {
  //handle logout logic
  res.redirect("/");
});

module.exports = router;
```

In the index.js file I have set prefix to be '/admin';

Can I know extract this prefix in the admin.js file?
Like for example:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

// Require prefix
const prefix = router.getPrexix()?

router.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("admin", { title: "Admin Menu", prefix });
});

router.get("/settings", function(req, res) {
  res.render("admin/settings", { title: "Admin Menu | Settings", prefix });
});

router.get("/logout", function(req, res) {
  //handle logout logic
  res.redirect("/");
});

module.exports = router;
```

Would it be possible to do this?
I could reuse '/admin' in the pug templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Express, [`req.baseUrl`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.baseUrl) is the URL that the router was mounted on which would be `"/admin"` in your case.

And, you have [`req.path`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.path) which is what the route matched.

And, you have [`req.originalUrl`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.originalUrl) is the original URL so you can always use this in combination with either of the above to see the whole picture.

Here's a little example to illustrate:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/new", (req, res) => {
    console.log("baseUrl", req.baseUrl);                // "/admin"
    console.log("path", req.path)                       // "/new"
    console.log("originalUrl", req.originalUrl);        // "/admin/new"
    res.send("new");
});

app.use("/admin", router);

app.listen(80);
```

Comment: @luckyluke - Did this answer your question? If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.